# Magento import customer data with link up order data

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Because of some issue I rollback database and found that 3 customers are deleted but that customer's order remain as it is.

Now What I need to do is import customer details which are deleted with associated order.

I try to import customer details using csv file and then replace "entity_id" with the old id.
entity_id changed successfully but still I can't see order details on customer details.

Please help me how can I link existing order data with new customer.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parag, you can try to load the order and than set the customer id again something like this

```
$yourOrderId = 123;  
$yourCustomerId = 3454;

$_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($yourOrderId);
$_order->setCustomerId($yourCustomerId);
$_order->save();
```

Please take the db backup before making any change

Comment: Hey! Ram, thanks for your replay. But can you please tell me where i need to write this code?? Because when i try to write this code in new file then I got error.

Comment: you can create file in the root directory and add the following things on top of the page require_once 'app/Mage.php'; Mage::App('default'); and reindex the data once you done with your work.

Answer (score 0):

Since it only 3 customers you could also just manually update the order table (assuming that you have access to the database)

```
UPDATE `sales_flat_order` SET `customer_id`='{customer_id}' WHERE `entity_id`='{order_id}';
```